# How to make mysql request with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to convert my sql row to doctrine object.

```
SELECT * FROM t_download GROUP BY download_yt_id ORDER BY download_id DESC LIMIT 50
```

I have maked that but that doesn't work :

```
$Download = new Download();


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $query
            ->select('distinct :id')
            ->from('DimiYvmBundle:Download', 'd')
            ->orderBy(':id', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('id', $Download->getId());


        $query->setMaxResults(50);

        $lastdl = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

My Entity Download with getter and setters:

```
    namespace Dimi\YvmBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    class Download
    {

        private $id;

        private $ytId;

        private $date;

        private $title;

        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

    public function setYtId($ytId)
        {
            $this->ytId = $ytId;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getYtId()
        {
            return $this->ytId;
        }

        public function setTitle($title)
        {
            $this->title = $title;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getTitle()
        {
            return $this->title;
        }

        public function setDate($date)
        {
            $this->date = $date;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getDate()
        {
            return $this->date;
        }

        public function getLastDownload()
        {
            // SELECT * FROM t_download GROUP BY download_yt_id ORDER BY download_id DESC LIMIT 50
        }

    }
```

I would like to include in my model my getLastDownload method. Do you know how I can do that ?

Thanks you all for your helping.
Best regards,

Comment: What do you mean with `that doesn't work`?

Comment: $query->select('DISTINCT d.id')
            ->from('DimiYvmBundle:Download', 'd')
            ->orderBy('d.id', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(50);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something simple as this?

```
$query->select('d')
        ->from('DimiYvmBundle:Download', 'd')
        ->orderBy('d.id', 'DESC')
        ->andWhere('d.id', ':id')
        ->setParameter('id', $Download->getId());

$lastdl = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: The d.id isn't unique? So if you select only one in the andWhere() you never get 50 result.